# Inserting element value after 'onchange' function into localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm creating some kind of the function to add/update the input value on change listener into local storage to save the values when the user will refresh the page. Currently Everything is working just fine but if I type to the input A it will save to the local storage but if I type to the input B it will replace the value which was added before from input A. Is there any way how can I save value from all this elements without replacing values of each other ??? Thanks

**Below is my current code for the reference :)**

```js
let input_items_array = [];

input_items_array.push(job_number,client_company,account_holder,ans_note,customer_name,customer_phone,
        email,fault_reported,service_id,vehicle_rolling,additional_eq,vehicle_reg,make_self,model_self,
        version_self,colour_self,engine_size_self,fuel_self,transmission_self,engine_no_self,body_self,kw_self,
        odometer_type_self,address,vehicle_destination,schedule_flag,eta,tolls,drivers_notes,call_centre_comms);

input_items_array.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('change', event => {
        let data_array = [];
        data_array.push(el.value);
        localStorage.setItem('data_array', JSON.stringify(data_array));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are pushing only one value `el.value` to the array and then saving it to the local storage which, in turn, overrides the local storage with the new value.

What you need is to keep track of the values stored in local storage then update them with your new value.

There are two ways you can do this:

### 1.Create multiple local storage items for each input:

To do that, your function should look like this

```
input_items_array.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('change', event => {
        localStorage.setItem(el.name, el.value);
    });
});
```

and make sure each input item have a descriptive name

### 2.Make your local storage as an object

To do that your function will look like this

```
// Initialize `data_array` local storage so it can be retrieved later
localStorage.setItem('data_array', JSON.stringify({}));

input_items_array.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('change', event => {
        let storedObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data_array'));
        storedObj[el.name] = el.value;
        localStorage.setItem('data_array', JSON.stringify(storedObj));
    });
});
```

again, you need to make sure that each input item have a descriptive name

Comment: thank you , but i'm getting this error : Cannot set property 'x of null

Comment: Do you get it when trying the first or the second solution?

Comment: does `el.name` have a value? because you need to make sure that your input element has name attribute so that `el.name` get a value and not return `null`

Comment: Also, one thing I noticed that I messed: The local storage should be there before adding to it. so `localStorage.setItem('data_array', JSON.stringify({}));` should be added before the function. check the updated answer of the second solution